# how to decrement the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm wondering if there is any possible way to decrement the loop in python? I’ve searched on many websites but I didn’t find anything helpful.
For example, I was thinking about this simple function:

```
def fun():
    colors = ["red", "grn", "blu", "prpl"]
    i = 0
    while 4 > i >= 0:
        for i, r in enumerate(colors):
            us = input("Enter your color\n")
            if us == 'red':
                i += 1
                print("r:", r)
            else:
                print("sorry, no", us, "enter the color again")
                i -= 1
```

If the input equals to `'red'` increment the `i`, else decrement it.
Then I noticed that in/decrement doesn’t affect the `i` anyhow.
How can I decrement the `i` if the input wasn’t `'red'`?

EDIT:
I’m sorry, my question wasn’t clear. The program is iterating the list `colors`, once the `us` doesn't equals to `red` the program must decrement the `i`. Below is the desired output sample I hope it's clear now.

Desired output sample:

```
Enter your color
red
r: red

Enter your color
red
r: grn

Enter your color
r
sorry, no r enter the color again
Enter your color
red
r: grn
```

Comment: You will have to use a `while` loop and manage the `i` because using `for` loop loops on the iteraor created from the list which means at the start of each iteration `i` I will get the next value no matter how you changed it. In a `while` loop you are free to change `i` however you please

Comment: Python doesn't have the same syntax as the `for` loop in C or other languages. Kind of requires some getting used to at first. If you want to have an array index, for instance, that increments or decrements by variable amounts on each iteration, you just declare them above the `for` statement, and in the loop increment them as you have it above. If you need to control the amount a variable increments each time through a loop, you could use `for i in range(0, 10, 2):` for instance. The last parameter is the `step`.

Comment: He could use a for loop too with a range(). @Tomerikoo But yeah.. for this specific case a while may be better.

Comment: @Todd looping on indexes or elements have the same effect. Bottom line, each iteration `i` will get the next value from the iterator no matter if you changed it. If you mean using `range` with a `step`, then the logic has to be consistant. Here OP is counting on user input so I don't see how that will hold

Comment: What do you mean by "decrement the loop" are you trying to go back an iteration or reduce the current index variable value?

Comment: Sometimes a `for` loop is appropriate if you have a value you want to increment as usual, but other values that can vary can be vars declared outside the loop. But yes. You are correct @Tomerikoo if what you're saying is you can't cause the iterator/generator in the `for` statement to modify its progression.

Comment: @Sayse I meant decrement the loop to go back an iteration, I edited the question hope it's clear now.

Comment: @LaLa why do you declare a list of colors, but not use it for anything? You don't need that list to implement the loop at all.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, your code in the question *is* updating `i`. But `i` just gets reassigned the current value generated by the enumerator each iteration.

```
...     i = 0
...     while 4 > i >= 0:
...         for i, r in enumerate(colors):
```

Let's focus on the two loops you have in your code. The outermost `while` loop looks fine. You have a range of values you want `i` to stay within in order to continue looping. Great.

In the inner loop, you're using `enumerate()` to create a generator that produces a sequence of tuples: `(0, 'red'), (1, 'grn'), (2, 'blu'), (3, 'prpl')`   And in that same statement, you assign `i` with the numeric value in each tuple, and `r` with the color.

Each time through the inner loop, `i` is a value 0 to 3 and 'r' is a color (which is never used for anything). The values of `i` and `r` are going to be set to the next tuple in the list on each iteration **no matter what you assign to them within the loop**.

You could probably, actually get rid of the inner for loop, and your program will still work. Without the inner loop, you'll just loop until `i` goes out of range.

However, because you have an inner loop, your number of iterations is multiplied by the number of tuples `enumerate()` produces.  So say the outer loop cycles through 4 times, because of that inner loop, you're going to have to answer the input question 4 (outer) * 4 (inner) = 16 times.

You should consider reimplementing with just one loop - no inner.

So, the question states, "how do you decrement the loop in python." Do this if you want to count backward - or use a while loop to have more control over i:

```
>>> for i in range(10, 0, -1):
...     print(i)
```

So per the comment thread, the `for` loop in Python causes iteration over the values specified in the `for` statement in the predictable order specified.

If you want `i` to iterate over integer values 1 to 100, but increment by 2 each time through the loop, you could code it as:

```
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
```

If however, you want `i` to vary in different ways based on code within the loop, this would be more appropriate:

```
i = 0
while i < 20:
    i += 1
    ri = random.randint(0 , 5)
    if ri == 2:
        i += 2
    elif ri == 3:
        i -= 1
    elif ri = 0:
        break;
```

So the variable `i` is easily updated dynamically by code in the loop. The syntax is just different from C in this case. You can also force a Python loop to break out of the loop using `break` as in C - so that's one way to alter the sequence after it starts.

The for loop relies on a generator or iterator to give it a new item (or items) that it can assign to a loop var (or vars) each time through the loop. Once in motion, the generator or iterator supplies each sequential item it was configured/coded to produce. You can't make it back up, or change the amount it increments after the loop has started. You're committed.

A good example of a generator object is `range(0, 10, 2)`. That's not actually the generator - it returns a generator at the start of the looping. And the for loop asks this generator for each next value until it's hit its limit.

And a good example of an iterator is:

```
>>> for foo in ['the', 'quick', 'fox']:
...     print(foo)
```

The list is not the iterator - one is created for the list implicitly. This iterator will produce each item in the list in the order given until it runs out of items.

So, as I said, once the for loop starts underway, the values it goes through are pretty much predetermined... until today.. =) I have to make this clear: **the following code is only 'for fun'.** Don't write code like this for your projects.

In the loop below, `variable_indices()` produces a generator.

```
>>> import random
>>> variable_index = 0
>>>
>>> def variable_indices(min, max, step):
...     global variable_index
...     variable_index = min
... 
...     while variable_index >= min and variable_index < max:
...         variable_index += step
...         print(f"variable_indices() producing value: {variable_index}")
...         yield variable_index
...         
>>> for i in variable_indices(0, 10, 1):
... 
...     if random.randint(0, 2) == 2:
...         print("updating variable_index -= 1")
...         variable_index -= 1
...         
variable_indices() producing value: 1
variable_indices() producing value: 2
updating variable_index -= 1
variable_indices() producing value: 2
updating variable_index -= 1
variable_indices() producing value: 2
variable_indices() producing value: 3
variable_indices() producing value: 4
variable_indices() producing value: 5
updating variable_index -= 1
variable_indices() producing value: 5
variable_indices() producing value: 6
variable_indices() producing value: 7
updating variable_index -= 1
variable_indices() producing value: 7
variable_indices() producing value: 8
variable_indices() producing value: 9
variable_indices() producing value: 10
```

`variable_indices` should, as any generator, render values in a predictable progression. But in this case I did a bad thing and made its internal state depend on a global variable - which I then modify within the loop. I guess this could serve to demonstrate that it's not straightforward to do this sort of thing, and therefore you shouldn't =)